# Access native code from system service in android

Tags: android

I am trying to build a custom ROM [from CyanogenMod source] with my own system service added to it. I have created the interface ( .aidl) and wrote myserver in java. The system_server adds my service and starts it during system boot without any problem. I have a code written in c that i want to use from my service.

The first thing i tried to do was:

```
/frameworks/base/services/jni/com_android_server_MyService.cpp

/* includes and namespace ... */
static jint android_server_MyService_initialize(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
   return 10;
}

static JNINativeMethod sMethods[] = {
   {"initialize", "()I", (void*)android_server_MyService_initialize}
};
int register_android_server_MyService(JNIEnv* env){
  return jniRegisterNativeMethods(env, "com/android/server/INSAService", sMethods, NELEM(sMethods));
 }
```

... added the above file in the corresponding Android.mk as a source

It builds without any problem but i am having problem accessing this method from my service (the java part)

calling my native method causes a problem with the following error message

```
 w/dalvikvm(  278): No implementation found for native Lcom/android/server/MyService;.native_initialize:()V
```

Comment: You might want to share what exactly is the problem... Is this code linked in whatever library you are using? Is your service loading the library without error?

Comment: Here's the error message i get after displaying a message from the constructor inside my service (on the log)                                        "w/dalvikvm (  278): No implementation found for native Lcom/android/server/MyService;.native_initialize:()V"

Comment: You are either the .com prefix or your Java code is in the wrong package

Comment: my java code is in "com.android.server" package. It resides with code for AlarmManagerService.java ... i did the same thing. I have added com_android_server_MyService.cpp as a source in /frameworks/base/services/jni/Android.mk

Comment: what do you mean by "You are either the .com prefix"?

Comment: I forgot to add register_android_server_MyService method to onload.cpp in the same 'jni' directory. @NikolayElenkov thank you for your time.